# Sinus series convergence/divergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)
$$

Knowing that for the small numbers

$$ x \geq \sin x $$

and then i have a sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)
$$

Which by limit comparsion test:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{\frac \pi {2^n}}{\frac 1 {2^n}}\right) = \pi
$$

so it is convergent?

Comment: Did you try checking if it were... say... geometric?  That would show convergence.  And you shouldn't use the limit comparison test unless the summand is complicated btw.

Comment: You need to argue that the terms are positive for $n$ large enough, but otherwise this seems right

Comment: The comparison with geometric series should be enough if it starts being true for all $n>n_0$ for some $n_0$ and keeps being true for infinite of terms.

Comment: This is essentially correct. Don't forget, though, to mention that $0\le\sin(x)\le x$ for all $x\in[0,\pi/2]$. You should also notice that the series $\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{\pi}{2^n}$ is a geometric series.

Comment: Note that $\sum_{n\ge1} \frac{\pi}{2^n} = \pi \sum_{n\ge1} 2^{-n} = \pi \cdot 1 = \pi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series is absolutely convergent since:$$
\left|\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^n}\right)\right|\le\frac{\pi}{2^n}=\pi\left({1\over 2}\right)^n
$$
and $\pi\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left({1\over 2}\right)^n$ is a geometric series with ratio $<1$ thus convergent.

Comment: It is not necessary to invoke **absolute** convergence : all terms are $>0$...

Comment: Besides, saying that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}1/2^n$ is a geometric series with ratio <1 thus convergent would not be superfluous in a fully satisfying explanation...

Comment: thank you JeanMarie! I know that an answer is fully satisfying when superfluous comments appear on the bottom.

Comment: I take your comment with humor...